# INSERT INTO SELECT with VALUES in one query

Tags: php, mysql

Bit new to MYSQL and PHP - I have the following code that will create a new record in multiple tables that I have setup however I need to merge the following code together somehow as it creates separate rows instead of one record

```
$sql .=("INSERT INTO orders (customer_id) SELECT customer_id FROM 
customer_details;");    

foreach($result as $item){
$mysql_desc = $item['product_description'];
$mysql_mode = $item['delivery_mode'];
$mysql_cost = $item['course_cost'];
$sql .=("INSERT INTO orders(product_description, delivery_mode, course_cost) VALUES('$mysql_desc', '$mysql_mode', '$mysql_cost');");
}
```

The result I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Now would be a great moment to read up on prepared and bound statements

Comment: I can't tell which of those records is supposed to have a problem, if any.  My strong advice to you would be to use prepared statements here.  This would eliminate a lot of potential uncertainty with your `INSERT` query.  Strawberry's comment has been upvoted, sadly I can only do it once.

Comment: Please provide us a `print_r($sql);` result  after `foreach` - to see full query

Comment: Will switch to mysqli asap.  I need record 53 to have a product description, delivery_mode and course cost.  At the moment I can get one without the other.

Comment: Also `mysqli_query` can't work with multiply statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data I assume that you want to insert the customer id and the values from php into the same record. In this case you need to combine them into the same `insert ... select ...` statement:

```
$sql .=("INSERT INTO orders(customer_id, product_description, delivery_mode, course_cost) select customer_id, '$mysql_desc', '$mysql_mode', '$mysql_cost' from customer_details;");
```

Couple of things to note:

1. This `insert ... select ...` statement will insert the same records for all customers in the customer details table. I'm not sure if this is your ultimate goal.
2. Pls consider the advices made in the comments regarding the old mysql API and the use of prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks! That got the result I was after.

Comment: @ParkProductions then why did you remove the acceptance?

Comment: Hey haven't tried Nigel's answer, sorry to jump the gun - will state that this code works for the question asked for anyone else reading.  Unrelated to this part of the code I am getting a normal entry on first submission however an unexpected loop on my results page with on second submission.

Answer (score 0):

To put this more into what I would expect to happen, something along the lines of - prepare statement, then loop through each item and add in new row...

```
$insert = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (customer_id,product_description, delivery_mode, course_cost)
VALUES (?,?,?,?)");    

foreach($result as $item){
    $customerID = 1; // Have to ensure this is what your after
    $mysql_desc = $item['product_description'];
    $mysql_mode = $item['delivery_mode'];
    $mysql_cost = $item['course_cost'];
    $insert->execute([customerID,mysql_desc,mysql_mode,mysql_cost]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Nigel this works apart from the customerID.  Currently the value I want customerID to equal is from an auto increment 'customer_id' from another table called customer_details - any idea on how to include it in the foreach loop?

Comment: Depends on how this number is generated, is there a `SELECT` you can do or is this row inserted before hand.  If the later - have you looked into http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php, fetch this prior to entering the loop (as the insert will potentially change the value) and then set it as above.